# Why is so much of modern mathematics rooted in Germany?

Tags: geography

Whenever I read some Mathematic theories, I find it they are typically done by some people living in Germany. Eg: Riemann, Gauss, Moses Schoenfinkel etc. I want to know what Germany did to arise so many Mathematicians?

Comment: At the time of Gauss and Riemann Germany did not even exist. Instead it was a collection of independent German-speaking states, principalities... As for Moses Il"ich Schoenfinkel, read his Wikipeadia page.

Comment: After the formation of the German Empire, Chancellor (?) Otto von Bismarck strongly promoted science and engineering, which seems to have been a novelty for the times.

Comment: So you never read about theories of Lagrange, Cauchy, Galois, Lobachevsky, Boole, Hamilton, Peano, Poincare, Lebesgue, Cartan, Kolmogorov, Banach, Schwartz, von Neumann, Tarski, MacLane, Grothendieck, Atiyah, Mandelbrot, Yau, Gromov, Wiles, Voevodsky, Perelman or Tao?

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/666/why-were-20th-century-german-scientists-so-impressive/672#672

Comment: One factor certainly is that the state in Germany promoted collective economic development in the late 19thC (at a time when Britain, for example, was still hidebound by liberal economic thought), and that causes the demand and usefulness of scientific innovations to increase. Growing industrialisation - especially where there is widespread craft production - also gives people more opportunity to study and more mental stimulus.

Comment: What is amusing also is that between French and German, sometimes the same theorem is name after a French or a German who worked on it in some way, depending on which side of the border you are. Sometimes Russian mathematician names are appended to, when the result is presented by Russians...

Comment: George Green, Arthur Cayley, James Clerk Maxwell, William Rowan Hamilton, George Stokes, Lord Rayleigh, James MacCullagh, George F. FitzGerald etc - Riemann studied mostly applied mathematics as well - it's just he is known for his sole number theory paper.